# MVC5 EF6 How to store user in model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to store owners (users) of some entity. I tried some type of this code, but Owners are always empty when i get groups in controller.

```
public class GroupsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = 
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // GET: TestCreator/Groups
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var allGroups = db.Groups.ToArray();
        var myGroups = allGroups.Where(g => g.Owners.Contains(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        return View(myGroups);
    }

...

public Group(List<string> owners, string name, Grade grade = 0)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Owners = owners;
        Name = name;
        Grade = grade;
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
```

Here is part of the model

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Owners { get; set; }
```

And here is part of database initializer

```
        var gr1 = new Group(new List<string>() { user.Id }, "5б")
        {
            Students = stud1
        };
        db.Groups.Add(gr1);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Problem is, that if i see at db.Groups right after db.SaveChanges() there is our group with one owner (current user). But when i see at db.Groups from controller, there is no owner (empty list). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you please show the code where you assign users to groups?

Comment: Oh, i found some info, that EF provide no possibility to store list of simple types. So i create simple class with Id and Name properties.